# A HTML container doesn't scroll properly after the position of its child is changed

Tags: javascript, html, css

To understand my problem you can see the jsfiddle I've created.

https://jsfiddle.net/hxzLeL6x/2/

When you click on the second image, the gray container which contains the two images slips towards left until the second image is at the extreme left of its father.

The father, as you can see, doesn't scroll properly after its child has been moved.

How can I solve the problem?

Here below the HTML code

```
<div id="tapeContainer">
    <div id="tape">
       <img id="firstImage" src="http://www.fotosd.it/wp-content/uploads/paesaggio-montano-della-val-di-fassa-in-estate_imagelarge.jpg">

       <img id="secondImage" src="http://www.improntaunika.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/paesaggio20toscano.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the css code

```
#tapeContainer{
  overflow: scroll;
  width:600px;
}

#tape{
  background-color: #616161;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width:3000px;
}

img{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

And finally, the javascript code

```
document.getElementById("secondImage").addEventListener("click", onImageClick.bind(null));


function onImageClick(e) {
            var clickedImage = e.currentTarget;
            var displacement = 0;


            var targetPosition = document.getElementById("tapeContainer").getBoundingClientRect().left;
            var tape = document.getElementById("tape");
            move();


            function move() {
                displacement += 1;
                tape.style.setProperty("right", displacement + "px");

                if(clickedImage.getBoundingClientRect().left !== targetPosition)
                {
                    setTimeout(move, 1);
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely obvious from your question what _should_ happen:  I can see what's happening, but I don't know what you _want_ it to do.

Comment: Which element do you mean by "father"? Are you referring to `tapeContainer` or `tape`? Why do you think it does not scroll? What do you want to happen?

Comment: @SeanWerkema 
1) Click the second image: as you can see, the tape slips towards left and instead of the first image, now at the begginning you have the second image.

2) Now you want to scroll the tape so that you have the default position, but this is not possible... because you can't scroll left.

Comment: @JackA I mean #tapeContainer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this gets you the functionality you require in a much simpler way:

```
function onImageClick(e) {
    var clickedImage = e.currentTarget;        
    var tapeContainer = document.getElementById("tapeContainer");
    tapeContainer.scrollLeft = clickedImage.offsetLeft;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hxzLeL6x/3/

If you would like to retain the animation you can use this code:

```
function onImageClick(e) {
    var clickedImage = e.currentTarget;        
    var tapeContainer = document.getElementById("tapeContainer");
    var goal = clickedImage.offsetLeft;
    move();

    function move() {
        if(tapeContainer.scrollLeft < goal) {
            tapeContainer.scrollLeft += 1;
        }

        if(tapeContainer.scrollLeft > goal) {
            tapeContainer.scrollLeft -= 1;
        }

        if(Math.round(tapeContainer.scrollLeft) != goal) {
            setTimeout(move, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hxzLeL6x/14/

Comment: Thanks!

This seems to be a valid, alternative solution. 

I'll try to implement a solution using the property scrollLeft. 

Your code works properly, but there is not the "low motion", which is a part of the software requirement specifications.

Comment: @ErroreFatale The key here is that you need to use the `scrollLeft` property to get  the scroll bar to do what you want. So use that instead of `tape.style.setProperty("right", displacement + "px");`. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/hxzLeL6x/6/

Comment: @JackA. thanks, I've posted an anwser with your code.

Comment: @ErroreFatale See my edit which caters for your animation requirement.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to use the property scrollLeft instead of changing the position of #tape.

The updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hxzLeL6x/9/

The following line of javascript

```
tape.style.setProperty("right", displacement + "px");
```

is replaced by this one

```
document.getElementById("tapeContainer").scrollLeft = displacement;
```